# How to get a List of DataAnnotation Display Name

Tags: c#, .net, data-annotations

I have a class with Data Annotations and need to get a list of strings from Display and attribute Name.

I already try some approaches.
In method GetAttributesNames().

```
internal class TVSystemViewData : BaseViewData
        {
            [Display(Name = "BoxType", Description = "")]
            public String BoxType { get; set; }

            [Display(Name = "BoxVendor", Description = "")]
            public String BoxVendor { get; set; }

            [Display(Name = "ClientId", Description = "")]
            public String ClientId { get; set; }

            [Display(Name = "HostName", Description = "")]
            public String HostName { get; set; }

            [Display(Name = "OSVersion", Description = "")]
            public String OSVersion { get; set; }
            [Display(Name = "SerialNumber", Description = "")]
            public String SerialNumber { get; set; }


            internal void GetAttributesNames()
            {
                var listOfFieldNames = typeof(TVSystemViewData)
                .GetProperties()
                .Select(x =>  x.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DisplayAttribute), true))
                .Where(x => x != null)
                .ToList();

            }
}
```

Comment: So what does or doesn't this do? You'll have to cast the attributes to `DisplayAttribute` in order to access their `Name` property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this might help

```
internal List<string> GetAttributesNames()  //changed type returned
    {
        return  typeof(TVSystemViewData)
          .GetProperties()                //so far like you did
          .SelectMany(x=>x.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DisplayAttribute),true) //select many because can have multiple attributes
          .Select(e=>((DisplayAttribute)e))) //change type from generic attribute to DisplayAttribute
          .Where(x => x != null).Select( x => x.Name) //select not null and take only name
          .ToList(); // you know ;)
    }
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var data = new TVSystemViewData();

        var listOfDisplayNames = data.GetAttributesNames();
    }
}

internal class TVSystemViewData
{
    [Display(Name = "XXXXX", Description = "")]
    public String BoxType { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "BoxVendor", Description = "")]
    public String BoxVendor { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "ClientId", Description = "")]
    public String ClientId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "HostName", Description = "")]
    public String HostName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "OSVersion", Description = "")]
    public String OSVersion { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "SerialNumber", Description = "")]
    public String SerialNumber { get; set; }

    internal List<string> GetAttributesNames()
    {
        return typeof(TVSystemViewData)
            .GetProperties()
            .Select(x => ((DisplayAttribute) x.GetCustomAttribute(typeof(DisplayAttribute), true)).Name)
            .ToList();
    }
}
```